# uninitialized constant ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 classes:
1.  Article

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_articles
  has_many :subcategories_articles
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_articles
  has_many :subcategories, :through => :subcategories_articles
end
```

2.Category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :articles  
  has_many :categories_articles  
  has_many :categories_subcategories  
  has_many :subcategories, :through => :categories_subcategories  
  has_many :articles, :through => :categories_articles  
end
```

3.The third class is the union of the first two, category_article

```
class CategoryArticle < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :category  
  belongs_to :article  
end
```

so, when i called in the view

```
<% f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_blank:"selects"},{class:'form-control select2 multi', :required=>true, multiple: true}) %>
```

I  get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Article::CategoriesArticle
```

The same goes for the class Subcategory and subcategory_article

Comment: Use four spaces or the `{}` button to format code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
has_many :category_articles
```

And

```
has_many :subcategory_articles
```

You'll also have to change these:

```
has_many :categories, :through => :categories_articles
has_many :subcategories, :through => :subcategories_articles
```

To something like:

```
has_many :categories, :through => :category_articles
has_many :subcategories, :through => :subcategory_articles
```

Rails doesn't pluralize both components of the composite table names. Just the last component.

Comment: Never pluralize in the middle, always, and only at the end. It's never `examples_links` and will be instead `example_links`.